# add to the sql table random number

Tags: sql, random

I have a table with 4 columns say

```
-----------------------
|data1|data2|data3|key|
-----------------------
|d1   | d2  | d3  | k1|
-----------------------
|d3   |d4   | d5  | k2|
-----------------------
|d6   | d7  | d8  | k1|
-----------------------
|d9   |d10  | d11 | k2|
-----------------------
```

I need to generate a new table based on this one with the same columns + id. Id should be random int64. same key should have same id
For example for above table it could be :

```
----------------------------
|data1|data2|data3|key| id |
----------------------------
|d1   | d2  | d3  | k1|1234|
---------------------------
|d3   |d4   | d5  | k2|5678|
----------------------------
|d6   | d7  | d8  | k1|1234|
----------------------------
|d9   |d10  | d11 | k2|5678|
----------------------------
```

I`ll be glad to get advices

> Upd

GUID is 128bit, I need 64 bit. I have a support for IRAND

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Perhaps it supports IRAND or RAND?

Comment: Is it a key (which implies uniqueness), or is it random (which implies it might repeat?) Could you give us a little background on why you want to do this, and why something like a GUID or a hash isn't more appropriate? (And yes, as @jarlh says, when doing something this unusual, you may need custom features of a particular RDBMS, so what system are you using?)

Comment: @jalh, @ Matt Gibson  please see in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
It will give a random number.
you can use `concat` for your solution.

```
select  ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT S.*, I.`id`
FROM `Table1` AS S
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT `key`, ROUND((POW(2,63)-1) * RAND()) AS id
      FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT `key`
         FROM `Table1`) AS lKeys 
   ) AS I ON S.`key` = I.`key`
```